# MVC 4 ADO.net DatabaseFirst working with database

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

I am writing project on ASP.NET MVC 4. The database for this project was not originally designed, and the modification or addition of new tables in the database is done campaign work. I use ADO.NET EF DatabaseFirst. During the work I needed additional properties to store information that I have ordered in the class with the fields of the database.
After that, I need to add a new table, but all of my follow-up in class with fields disappeared after the model update ADO.NET. Who knows how to safely modify my model no change of work already done?? Thanks in advance.